# fxml loader exception "root value is already specified" I never specified a root value

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I am trying to have a hyperlink open a new window. I have copied the fxml loader method from other parts of my code that work without issue. For some reason I am getting an fxml loader exception issue that says the root value is already specified. I have not specified a root value anywhere in my code. I also have not specified a controller in the fxml because other answers on stackoverflow said this might be causing the issue.

this is the class that is loading the new Window. the issue occurs when trying to load `"/SellerProfileRegisterLayout.fxml"`

```
public class SwitchToSellerProfile {

    @FXML private BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    @FXML private TextField usernameLogin = new TextField();
    @FXML private PasswordField passwordFieldLogin = new PasswordField();
    @FXML private MainController mainController;
    @FXML private Hyperlink sellerProfileRegisterHyperLink = new Hyperlink();

    public SwitchToSellerProfile(MainController mainController){
        this.mainController = mainController;
    }
    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        sellerProfileRegisterHyperLink.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/SellerProfileRegisterLayout.fxml"));
                loader.setController(new SellerProfileRegisterController(this.mainController));
            this.mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().clear();
                this.mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().add(loader.load());
    // clicking the error always takes me here to the loader.load()
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the fxml for SwitchToSellerProfile

```xml
<BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="550.0" 
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="441.0" 
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" 
                   layoutX="162.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="228.0" 
                   text="Business Profile Sign In">
                <font>
                    <Font size="20.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="usernameLogin" layoutX="192.0" layoutY="132.0" promptText="Business Username" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="passwordFieldLogin" layoutX="192.0" layoutY="167.0" promptText="Business Password" />
            <Hyperlink fx:id="forgotPasswordHyperlink" layoutX="218.0" layoutY="200.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Forgot Password? " />
            <Label fx:id="incorrectLabel" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Wrong username or password" textFill="RED" visible="false" />
            <Button fx:id="btnLogin" layoutX="234.0" layoutY="235.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Sign In" />
            <Label layoutX="192.0" layoutY="274.0" text="Don't have one?">
               <font>
                  <Font size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Hyperlink fx:id="sellerProfileRegisterHyperLink" layoutX="283.0" layoutY="271.0" text="Register here">
               <font>
                  <Font size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Hyperlink>
        </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

the register controller and its fxml

```
public class SellerProfileRegisterController {

    private MainController mainController;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField = new TextField();
    @FXML private TextField businessEmail = new TextField();
    @FXML private Button registerBtn = new Button();
    @FXML private Hyperlink goBackLink = new Hyperlink();

    public SellerProfileRegisterController(MainController mainController){
        this.mainController = mainController;
    }
    @FXML private void initialize(){
        registerBtn.setText("Hello"); 
        // just to see if it works hint: it doesn't 
    }
}
```

```xml
<BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" 
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
     <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
          <children>
              <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" 
                     layoutX="181.0" layoutY="62.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="225.0" 
                     text="Seller Profile Register">
                  <font>
                      <Font size="20.0" />
                  </font>
              </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="210.0" layoutY="121.0" promptText="Business Name" />
            <TextField fx:id="businessEmail" layoutX="210.0" layoutY="162.0" promptText="Business Email Address" />
            <Button layoutX="229.0" layoutY="278.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Register Account" fx:id="registerBtn" />
            <Hyperlink layoutX="210.0" layoutY="311.0" text="Go back? " fx:id="goBackLink">
               <font>
                  <Font size="10.0" />
               </font></Hyperlink>
            <PasswordField layoutX="210.0" layoutY="200.0" promptText="Password" />
            <PasswordField layoutX="211.0" layoutY="238.0" promptText="Confirm Password" />
          </children>
      </Pane>
     </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The error message:

```
 javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
 user/IdeaProjects/FinalStore/target/classes/SellerProfileRegisterLayout.fxml
 user/IdeaProjects/FinalStore/target/classes/SellerProfileRegisterLayout.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2755)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2704)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at Store.SwitchToSellerProfile.lambda$initialize$0(SwitchToSellerProfile.java:38)
```

line 38 is the `loader.load()` that I commented on above.

So ideally `SellerProfileRegisterController` loads instead of a nothing happening and an error message to the console. I'm not sure what's causing this. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Don't initialize the `@FXML` annotated fields, they will be injected by the `FXMLLoader` (assuming proper `fx:id`s). Initializing them yourself is a waste of resources at best and can lead to subtle bugs at worst. (2) Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? It's possible you're using old compiled code. (3) If the problem persists, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and include the stack trace of the error. The currently posted code does not appear _minimal_ (or necessarily _complete_).

Comment: @Slaw I added the error message. I never know how much code to include. since this is from a larger project and I guess I don't see it with fresh eyes. are there any classes or anything I'm missing?

Comment: This kind of error happens, if you use `setRoot` before invoking `load()` or if you call `load` more than once.This doesn't seem to be the case here. Are you sure you successfully compiled this version of the lambda expression? Thy using the `Clean & Build` functionality of your IDE to make sure the current version of the code is used and check, if the outcome changes...

Comment: @Fabian yup that was it. clean & build fixed it. thanks for the help!